# How to write sql statement to newly added column with another table values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called `subject` and I added a new column `stdCount`.

There is another table called `enrollments` with columns `student_id`, `subject`, `year`, `marks`. Mainly this table records for each student which subjects he or she is enrolled in.

Now I need to get the student count for each unit from the `enrollments` table and update the `subject` table's `stdCount` column.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Update it with the number of students for that subject on average per year? Or the # of students for that subject in a particular year?

Comment: This is an example of a question that would greatly benefit from sample data and desired results.

Comment: no don't need any year specification ...  @BrianDeMilia

Comment: @Harshana what columns are on the SUBJECT table? Is there a year column on that table?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia need to update stdCount column of subject table from studentCount of Unit table

Comment: You never mentioned a "unit table" in your question, do you mean the "enrollments" table? In either case, what columns exist on the subject table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SUBJECT table has one row per subject, even if that subject is offered in 2+ years, and you want STDCOUNT to show the total number of students enrolled in all years throughout all of time:

```
update subject s
   set stdcount =
       (select count(*)
          from enrollments e
         where e.subject = s.subject)
```

If the SUBJECT table has one row per subject and year (and has a year column), and you want to show the total number of students enrolled in each (subject, year) combination:

```
update subject s
   set stdcount =
       (select count(*)
          from enrollments e
         where e.subject = s.subject
           and e.year = s.year)
```